# Should I put all of my view objects in package models when working with a playframework 2 application?

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I'm doing some tests with a playframework2 app and I have noticed that if I do not put
my objects in the models folder I'm not allowed to use them in my view.

e.g Let say I put a class SimpleObject in a package name simple.

**SimpleObject.class:**

```
public class SimpleObject {

    public SimpleObject(){}

    public SimpleObject(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

In my **Application** controller
i render the view with a new SimpleObject:

```
public static Result doSomeAction() {
    SimpleObject simpleObject = new SimpleObject("test");       
    return ok(test.render(simpleObject));
}
```

In my **test.scala.html**:

```
@(simpleObject: SimpleObject)
@main("Here is the result:") {
    @{simpleObject.getName()}
}
```

This results in an error:

```
not found: type SimpleObject
```

If I move SimpleObject to the package models it compiles and works.

In my other application I have implemented the Elasticsearch module. There I receive
an IndexResult that I want to loop over in my view. I get the same error as with the SimpleObject.

So my questions here is sort of architectural. Whats the "play 2 way" of handling this?
Should I implement a view object and a builder, throw the IndexResult object in and create
a view object? 
Or is there a way of telling my app to scan other packages too?
Maybe there is some other way of thinking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using an import in the view, ie:

```
@import simple._
```

Or you could try organizing your models/classes in sub-folders/packages of models.

Answer (score 1):

As **Jordan** wrote you have to `import` your package if it's not in `controllers`, `models`, `views`(which are imported by default)...

Other possibility is specifying the exact package in the declaration:

```
@(simpleObject: my.own.package.which.isnt.in.models.or.controllers.SimpleObject)
@main("Here is the result:") {
    @{simpleObject.getName()}
}
```